# Which role among these are suitable for "Administrator" in Agile Software Development Projects?

Tags: agile, software-development, dsdm

I did some research in DSDM and Agile Projects and got stuck in this scenario. I'm new to this so please help me out.

Suppose, in an organisation there are following posts:

1) Managing Director

2) Finance Manager

3) Analysts

4) **Administrator**

Admin has been with company since its formation and has in-depth knowledge of all aspects of company's business. He handles record keeping and client relations and wants efficient system.

5) Programmers   etc

Now, they hire a software development consultancy for upgrading their current system which uses static webpage, excel for storing data etc. The consultancy has facilitated workshops and will carry out Agile Development project. The posts i listed above wants to be involved in the project where they will have a new role.

Now my question is, will administrator be best suited to the role of Workshop Facilitator? I don't think so because workshop facilitator should be from outside the organisation to ensure neutrality right?

If not, **which role will be best suited for administrator?**

1) Business sponsor? 
I don't think administrator can make financial decisions and must be for a high position right?

2) Business Visionary?

3) Project manager?
Anyone with proper skills and knowledge in organisation can play this role right? Could it be admin?

4) Technical coordinator
I doubt if Administrator is skilled in technical field? or is he?

5) Business Ambassador
Administrator deals with client. Could he play this role?

6)Business Analyst?

7)Business Advisor?

8)Atern Coach?

So, which role would be most suitable for Administrator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align with DSDM, then the Administrator would best fit the Business Ambassador role. In fact, the Administrator sounds perfect for the role, if personal capabilities of the Administrator also align with the responsibilities outlined in DSDM.

Regardless of the project methodology applied, I believe it would be a mistake to not view the Administrator as a key source of accurate information about what the system actually has to do, what is required for an acceptable user experience, and how to place the system in context for the business users.

Comment: Thank you so much. finally, one more thing. would you mind giving me few reasons why he would not be fit to play the role of Workshop Facilitator?

Comment: You are possibly thinking that the Administrator has an understanding and rapport with the organization that would enhance the ability to facilitate, and in the context of general meetings, this is true. 

In the context of DSDM, the Administrator should not be the Workshop Facilitator because the Workshop Facilitator should be independent of the outcome to be achieved in the workshop. The Administrator is a key participant in the workshop who will contribute to and influence the outcomes.